Xcode predictive code completion not work with Image(systemName: )
When I want to use some system image I can't just remember them all, and I was hoping that new Xcode prediction will help here. But it does not know any even popular system images. Maybe I need to configure it somehow? Or just wait when Apple add this behaviour in next release?
I try to create Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass") and when I type "mag" I expect Xcode know all his system images names and can predict it, but have nothing.

Another term is "SF Symbols" you can download Apple's app and see them all
https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/
You can submit this as a feature request so Apple can train predictive completion.
